# Pandas DataFrame apply function debug

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, apply

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [4, 5, 3, 1, 2],
    'b': [20, 10, 40, 50, 30],
    'c': [25, 20, 5, 15, 10]
})

def second_largest1(df1):
    return df1[df1.argmax()-1]

print second_largest1(df['a'])
print second_largest1(df['b'])
print second_largest1(df['c'])
```

My 'second_largest1' funtion work show the results of df['a'] and df['b'], 4 and 40 respectively.

However, it does not work on df['c']. Why doesn't it work?

The error message is:

> KeyError: -1L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
def second_largest1(df1):
    return df1.nlargest(2).iloc[1]

print (second_largest1(df['a']))
4
print (second_largest1(df['b']))
40
print (second_largest1(df['c']))
20
```

Or [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
def second_largest1(df1):
    return df1.sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!